# How much grams oxygen is in 7 gram magnesiumnitrate? Mg(NO3)2

Tags: stoichiometry

I calculated this:
molar mass (M) of Mg(NO3)2 is 148,32 (24,3 + 2*14,01 + 6*16)
so when there is 7 grams Mg(NO3)2 there is 0,0472 mol (7/148,32)

But how do i find out how much of that is oxygen? Do i just divide by 8 and multiply by 6? (because 8 atoms of with 6 are oxygen)

Answer (score 1):

No. Each mole of the compound contains 6 moles of oxygen atoms, and has a mass of about 6 * 16 grams. You don’t have a mole, so use proportional reasoning to determine the actual mass in the sample.

To help to understand why it is simply a factor 6 and does not depend on the total number of atoms in the compound, perhaps imagine a chemical reaction that atomizes the compound:

$$\ce{Mg(NO3)2 ->[atomizer] Mg + 2N + 6O}$$

Irrespective of the number of other atoms in the compound, there are six moles of oxygen atoms for every mole of magnesium nitrate.

> Do i just divide by 8 and multiply by 6? (because 8 atoms of with 6 are oxygen)

No, that would not work because the other atoms are heavier or lighter than oxygen. You already incorporated the information about the other atoms in the compound when you divided by the molar mass of the compound.

Answer (score 0):

I did in this way:

Molecular masses:
Mg: 24.305;
N:14.007;
O: 15.999;

Total mass of Mg(NO3)2:
24.305 + (14.007*2) + (15.995*3*2) = 148.289 g/mol

Then the proportion:

Mass of oxigen in the molecule / total mass * 7 = (15.995*3*2)/148.289 *7 =4.53 g

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, i finally understand :)

Comment: Generally the right idea but numerous mistakes. **Molecular masses: Mg: 24.305; N:14.007; O: 15.999** - these are not molecular masses but rather atomic masses // **Total mass of Mg(NO3)2: 24.305 + (14.0072) + (15.9953*2) = 148.289 g/mol** the equation is wrong. It should be $24.305 + 2*(14.0072) + 6*(15.9953) = 148.291$g/mol

Comment: (cont.) Finally the mass of oxygen is wrong. It should be $$\dfrac{7}{148.291} \times 6 \times 15.9953 = 4.53$$ // not sure about how many significant figures should be in the answer. I'll assume 7.00 grams of the magnesium nitrate.